# Native WebApp (Webview loading website) Authentication on mobile Device

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web, oauth, cross-platform

Hi i am currently devoloping an app for multiple plattforms.
The idea is to load a website (ASP.NET) into a webview so that the UI looks the same on multiple OS.
Now my question is what is the best way to authenticate users so that they dont have to login every time they open the app.
My intention now is to use OAuth but i am not sure if this fits my situation because i am not securing a WebApi. If i decide to use OAuth i will have to develop my own OAuth server.
Note the app is able to use native functions

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you also own or control the website. If the website is yours  and you're simply trying to build a hybrid mobile app that will just leverage the content and functions of your existing website. Here are the things that you should consider:

- Assuming your website registers members instead of devices and now you want to auto sign in the users from your mobile app, if so the app would have to save the user's login credentials somewhere (e.g in settings). If you don't want to change your website, you could just use your mobile app to auto fill the username and password fields on the login page. You could alternatively create a mobile sign-in page that will take a direct post from the mobile app and authenticates the credentials without the end user having to tap on any button.
- You want to be careful with cookie based authentication, depends on the mobile platform and the webview control used your app may not be able to handle cookie without additional work. So you may consider switching to using tokens for securing the sessions.
- What you don't want is to change the website to also allow the registration of member devices. Going that route could really muddy the water.

If your goal is just to simplify the user login experience with minimum effort you may want to use a generic mobile authentication solution app such as the [ReadySignOn](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/readysignon/id1007775032?mt=8) app which suppose to work with OAuth right out of the gate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it helped me alot
I am building a hybrid mobile App and i  Control the Website 
Saving credencials on the device and create a sign-in page that will take a direct post from the mobile app is something i already thought about the only problem is that on rooted android devices you could read those credencials but that problem is solveable :)